# The line chart widget is FlutterFlow seems to fold on itself

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I have a problem with FlutterFlow line chart : Everything works nice until I add some values that are inferior.

Ex : Day 1 = 10;Day 2 = 20;Day 3 = 10;

If I do this, the chart seems to fold on itself.

Any ideas ?

I tried playing with the options,changing the type of graph,ect...